# Can I set up a COM Port that Connects via TCP/IP?

Tags: tcpip, serial, rs232

I have an RS232 device connected to a Digi PortServer on my network.  I can telnet to the Digi's IP and port number to communicate with that RS232 device.

I have a Windows application that knows how to talk to the device, but it wants to connect directly to an RS232 port.

So, my question: Is there some way to set up a COM port so that when this application connects to it, it goes through the network to the Digi to communicate with the device?

---

Here are some options I've found. Can anyone recommend for or against any of them?

- [Digi RealPort](http://www.digi.com/pdf/fs_realport.pdf)
- [TCP-Com](http://www.taltech.com/products/tcpcom.html)

Also found a bunch of links here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_port_redirector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the one provided by the hardware manufacturer, unless I thought there was something wrong with that one.